# Can we use two different topology for same topics in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I have two events PingData and OrderEvent(coming from two different producers) and both of them are going to do some modification on same resource (db,cache)

What is the ideal way to deal with this, I am able to think about following two possiblities 
1) single topics and topology and then filter on the basis of some data
2) Two different topics and two topologies which will perform some operations

Please guide me with the correct approach!

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is how inter related your two sources are. Do you want to have strict ordering guarantees across these 2 streams of data ? If so, start a singe topic with just one partition and have a consumer consume from it.

Now, this is not a very god setup as there is little/no parallelism. If your data has some key based partitioning, you can hash it and then have multiple partitions per topic. Now, you will have ordering guarantees for a single partition but no such guarantee across partitions. But if they are logically separate entities, I believe you should be fine.

If there is no dependence between the two datasets you are producing (I mean no strict ordering constraints), you should ideally separate it into 2 different logical namespaces by creating 2 topics.

The key point to remember is that "topic is just a logical entity in Kafka". In terms of performance, a single topic with 2 partitions is the same as 2 topics with 1 partition each.

A lot will therefore depend on how you want to design your system and the relationship between the two sets.